# Show that $A\setminus (B\setminus C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having difficulty showing this equality (assuming that the question doesn't have a typo).. I've tried in both directions and I can't seem to get what I need.

\begin{align}
A\setminus (B\setminus C)&=A\cap\overline{(B\cap \overline{C})}\\
&=A\cap(\overline{B}\cup C)\\
&=(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(A\cap C)\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap C)
\end{align}

And in the other direction (A bit more convoluted):

\begin{align}
(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B\cap C)&=(A\cap\overline{B})\cup(A\cap B\cap C)\\
&=[A\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup [B\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup [C\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\\
&=[A\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup [(B\cup A)\cap(B\cup\overline{B})]\cup [C\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\\
&=[A\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup [(B\cup A)\cap\mathcal{U}]\cup [C\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\\
&=[A\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup (B\cup A)\cup [C\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\\
&=[(A\cap \overline{B})\cup (A\cap \overline{B})]\cup(A\cup A)\cup B\cup C\\
&=(A\setminus B)\cup A\cup B\cup C
\end{align}

Both of these seem to be "close", but neither is the same, and neither quite get to the goal. Is there a flaw in my algebra? Or is this not even possible using this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $A\cap C = (A\cap B\cap C)\cup (A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)$ in the second-to-last last line of the first part:

$$\begin{align}A\setminus(B\setminus C)&=(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(A\cap C)
=(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)\cup(A\cap B\cap C)
\end{align}$$

Then note that $$(A\cap \overline{B})\cup(A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)=A\cap \overline B.$$

You need $$X\cup (X\cap Y)= X\tag{1}$$$$X\cap(Y\cup\overline{Y})=X\tag{2}$$

You can prove (2) if you know that:

$$X\cup\overline{X} = Y\cup\overline{Y}\tag{3}$$
$$X\cap (X\cup Y)=X\tag{4}$$

Proof of $2$ using $3,4$:

$$X\cap (Y\cup \overline Y)=X\cap (X\cup \overline X) = X$$

Comment: I vaguely recall this from some years ago -- what is this property/equality/law called? I'm referring to the addition of $B$ and $\overline{B}$ to both sides of a union

Comment: In general: $X = (X\cap B)\cup(X\cap \overline B)$. This follows because $X=X\cap (B\cup \overline{B})$, which is just saying that $B\cup\overline{B}$ is the entire universe. Not sure what that is called.

Comment: The second equality is that $X\cup(X\cap B)=X$. Again, not sure what that is called.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Using $^c$ to denote complement,
$$
A\setminus\left(B\setminus C\right)=A\cap\left(B\cap C^{c}\right)^{c}=A\cap\left(B^{c}\cup C\right)=A\cap\left(B^{c}\cup\left(B\cap C\right)\right).
$$